# AutoHotkey script for 'right click context menu' command

Tags: autohotkey

I am using a Macintosh keyboard on Windows and would like to create a hotkey so that I can turn <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and some other other button into the “right click context menu” button of non-mac keyboards.

What would such a script look like?

Let’s say I want to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as the “right click context menu” command.

I know the usage of AutoHotkey so I just want to know what the script would look like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key in question is the "Application" key (the one that brings up the context menu)..

Note: It's basically a shortcut key for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

In AuotHotKey the Application key can be referenced directly, as "AppsKey".

So

```
^r::AppsKey
```

should assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to behave as the Application Key.

More info (including specific references to the AppsKey) can be found in AutoHotKey's instructions on their site: [Remapping the Keyboard and Mouse](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

For a full set of addressable keys in AHK see their [List of Keys, Mouse Buttons, and Joystick Controls](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)